# restricting sheaves in projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, coherent-sheaves

I know that on $\mathbb{P}^3$ (it can be in $\mathbb{P}^n$,  but I just want to focus on $\mathbb{P}^3$), if one has an hiperplane $H \subset \mathbb{P}^3$, the equation of the hiperplane provides an exact sequence :

$$0 \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-1) \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3} \to \mathcal{O}_{H} (*)$$

from there, we can twist the sequence by a torsion free sheaf $F$ on $\mathbb{P}^3$, one has :

$F(-1) \to F \to F|_H \to 0$,

my question is, how to calculate the tor sheaves that appear when we tensor the sequence (*) by $F$ in order to obtain the second sequence, furthemore, it is possible to obtain a exact sequence of group cohomology like the following?

$$H^0(\mathbb{P}^3,F|_H) \to H^1(\mathbb{P}^3,F(-1)) \to H^1(\mathbb{P}^3,F)  $$

Any reference in Tor groups of torsion free sheaves are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: You have an injection in the above sequence, $0\to F(-1)\to F$, since the sheaf is torsion free. Are you asking about higher Tors?

Comment: Dear @Mohan, I am asking about this injection, is trivial to see that I have this injection? Because I think there are examples of torsion free modules that have non zero Tors. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Locally, the map $F(-1)\to F$ is just multiplication by the equation of the hyperplane and since $F$ is torsion free, the map is injective.

Comment: In fact, this is where I miss something, call the equation of the hiperplane by  $x$, this map $F(-1) \to F$ is  $.x\otimes id_F$, I don`t understand where the fact of being torsion free implies that $F$ is flat. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think this means flat? This only means $\mathrm{Tor}^1(F, \mathcal{O}_H)=0$, says nothing about higher tors. Flatness would mean all tors are zero too, for not just $\mathcal{O}_H$, but all sheaves.

Comment: Ahh, this was confusing me, now I think I got it, following your comment, one has that  if the multiplication by $x$ (the equation of the hyperplane) is not injective, then there exists one section $s \in F$ such that $x.s = 0$, but this means that $s$ is a torsion of the sheaf $F$, which can not occur?